# How can to use builder to initialise class when there are multiple similar build methods?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to create an instance of class which has some build methods. It is an imported class so not editable . When I try to call the build method it gives the error saying that

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public constructor Builder<PB : Any!, MB : Any!>() defined in com.messagebus.KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder
public open fun <P : Any!, M : Any!> Builder(): KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder<UUID!, Any!>! defined in com.messagebus.KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory
```

The code I am writing is in Kotlin and the KafkaMessageBusProducer class is in Java.

How can I resolve this conflict ?

my code

```
return  KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder<UUID, Any>()
                    .kafkaAddressPropertyName("portAddress")
                    .topic(topic)
                    .messageBusTypeSerializers(serializer)
                    .build().create(true)
```

the imported class file

```
public class KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory<P, M> extends MessageBusProducerFactory<P, M> {
    Environment env;
    KafkaCloudAppsProperties properties;

    public KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory(KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.env = builder.env;
        this.properties = new KafkaCloudAppsProperties(this.env, builder.kafkaAddressPropertyName);
    }

    
    public static <P, M> KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder<P, M> Builder() {
        return new KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder();
    }


    public static class Builder<PB, MB> extends com.cisco.wx2.messagebus.MessageBusFactory.Builder<KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder<PB, MB>, PB, MB> {
        Environment env;

        public Builder() {
        }

        public KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder<PB, MB> env(Environment env) {
            this.env = env;
            return this;
        }

        public KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory<PB, MB> build() {
            return new KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in that Builder, there is only one build() method.

Comment: in addition: ' It is an imported class so not editable'. Kotlin has extension functions and properties so even an external class is editable :)

Comment: @Stultuske yeah but it is showing conflict between method in KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder and build method of KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory

Comment: @Denise I doubt that. It's most likely between your Builder type and your Builder method (in your parent class, not the builder method in your Builder class)

Comment: @Stultuske how can I resolve this ?

Comment: @DanielJacob extensions cannot remove functions, and they can't extend the class itself (the entity that has the static members), only instances of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method names in Java should not start with a capital letter. Naming the method `Builder` causes it to overload the `Builder` class constructor in Kotlin, since Kotlin uses the same syntax for method and constructor calls.

If you have control of the Java class, you can do one of the following:

- Fix the name of your method (rename it `builder()`)
- Make the constructor private. It is redundant to the method anyway.
- Remove the method, since it is redundant to the constructor.

If you cannot modify the Java class, you could use a type alias to specify and call the constructor. (If the method did something different than the constructor and you needed to call the method, I don't know what you'd be able to do.)

```
typealias BuilderClass<P, M> = KafkaMessageBusProducerFactory.Builder<P, M>

//...

return  BuilderClass<UUID, Any>()
            .kafkaAddressPropertyName("portAddress")
            .topic(topic)
            .messageBusTypeSerializers(serializer)
            .build().create(true)
```